# How to prevent React from re-rendering every function in the function component

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, socket.io, react-state-management

I am having two users have a private message by having both of them join the same Socket.io room, which is based on the room created from the sender and receiver ids. Every time I create a message, the client rejoins the room, due to a Socket.io emit event re-rendering because of a state change, and the roomId is console logged.  As a result, the message is not being transmitted over multiple instances of the chat when it has joined the same room.

```
const ChatApp = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([]);
  const userId = useSelector(state => state.profile.profile._id);
  const senderFullName = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.fullname);
  const authId = useSelector(state => state.auth.user._id);
  const roomId = [authId, userId].sort().join('-');
  const ioClient = io.connect("http://localhost:5000"); 

    ioClient.emit('join', {roomid: roomId});
    ioClient.emit('connected', {roomid: roomId} );
    ioClient.on('message', (msg) => {
      const messageObject = {
        username: msg.from,
        message : msg.body,
        timestamp: msg.timestamp
      };
      addMessage(messageObject);
    });

  const addMessage = (message) => {
   const messagess = [...messages];
   messagess.push(message); 
   setMessages(messagess);
   console.log(messagess);   
   }

   const sendHandler = (message) => {
    var res = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a').toString();

    // Emit the message to the server
    ioClient.emit('server:message', {from: senderFullName, body: message, timestamp: res });
   }
   
     return (

<div className="landing">
<Container>
 <Row className="mt-5">
   <Col md={{ span: 8, offset: 2 }}>

     <Card style={{ height: "36rem" }} border="dark">
       <Messages msgs={messages} />
       <Card.Footer>
       <ChatInput onSend={sendHandler}>
         </ChatInput>
       </Card.Footer>
     </Card>
   </Col>
 </Row>
</Container>
</div>
   )
 };
```

Api code that is used in server

```
    io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
        // Everytime a client logs in, display a connected message
        console.log("Server-Client Connected!");

        socket.on('join', function(data) {

           socket.join(data.roomid, () => {
               //this room id is being console logged every time i send a message
               console.log(data.roomid);
           }); 

        });    

         socket.on('connected', function(data) {    
            //load all messages
            console.log('message received');
            (async () => {
                try {
                    console.log('searching for Schema');
            const conversation = await Conversation.find({roomId: data.roomid}).populate('messages').lean().exec();
            const mess = conversation.map(); 
            console.log(mess);   
            console.log('Schema found');    
            }
               catch (error) {
                   console.log('Schema being created');
                Conversation.create({roomId: data.roomid});
               }
        })();

    });

        socket.on('server:message', data => {
 
            socket.emit('message', {from: data.from, body: data.body, timestamp: data.timestamp});
            console.log(data.body);
            Message.create({from: data.from, body: data.body});

                
        })     
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either move the socket state up to a parent component, or move the event initialization into a custom hook that is shared once across your application, or into a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook here so it only runs on initial render.

Probably the simplest is the latter option, you can just wrap those lines of code you only want to be written once up like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ioClient.emit('join', {roomid: roomId});
    ioClient.emit('connected', {roomid: roomId} );
    ioClient.on('message', (msg) => {
      const messageObject = {
        username: msg.from,
        message : msg.body,
        timestamp: msg.timestamp
      };
      addMessage(messageObject);
    });
}, []);
```

The empty array at the end signifies that this will only run on initial render, and not again, as it has no dependencies.

---

**Update**

You may or may not be having closure or timing issues, but to be on the safe side, replace the line "addMessage(messageObject);`" with:

```
setMessages((previousMessages) => [messageObject, ...previousMessages]);
```

This will do the same thing as the `addMessage` function, but by passing a callback function to `setMessages`, you avoid using the state object from outside.

Comment: @luke-story I think this is making my state array reset to empty after each render. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Anything inside the above `useEffect` will only run once on initial mounting render of a component. If you find it is being done every render then something else is going wrong. Maybe try moving the initialisation up a few layers of components, to then be passed down.
Or write it in a new seperate custom hook that only runs once per entire app load.

Comment: Also @asdfcoder I had a closer look and your state-setting is a bit off, see my update for a fix

Comment: @luke-story thank you, the setMessages update fixed it